# Why are my feature layers not supported in ArcGIS Enterprise, but are in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I am trying to create a web map within ArcGIS Enterprise which will be used in Field Maps. My workflow has been:

- Create a map in Pro with four vector layers. These are all stored in a local geodatabase.
- Share as a web map to Enterprise, configured as "copy all data: editable".

When analyzed, I get one **24138** warning about `a single layer's pop-up definition including fields that aren't supported online`. A look at the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/analyzer-warning-messages/24138-layers-pop-up-definition-includes-one-or-more-measurement-field-that-is-not-supported-online.htm) says that the layer can be shared, but won't have those fields.

I also get a typical **00374** warning that `unique numeric IDs need to be assigned`.

I do so. I then share this Enterprise. The process runs and appears to work, but when I open up the web map I receive an error message saying that `the map cannot be drawn completely because one or more layers are not supported`. All four layers are listed in the Layers pane of the web map, but each with an error marking and none displaying.

If I follow this same workflow but publish to ArcGIS Online, I don't run into any problems.